# Any ideas on how to parallelize mysql_upgrade?

Tags: mysql

I am migrating from 5.5 to 5.6 and would like to speed up the mysql_upgrade process. I have thousands of databases per machine and 200 tables (innodb) per db. Any suggestion how to speed up the upgrade process?

Comment: I'll bet it is virtually I/O-bound, in which case multi-threading could not speed it up much.

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted your question because this is a common problem, and a solution would be welcome. But unfortunately, I believe that there is no way to parellalize it. mysql_upgrade always operates on the whole server directory, there is no way to only upgrade one database, and it reads the system tables.

Comment: I have this same issue with innodb crash recovery. The reading of the log file has to be single threaded in nature but there is no reason why the application can't be farmed out as a blocking thread on a table. When you work with a million tables, things like this take hours...

Comment: But currently it is single-threaded and works on the whole data directory, so I see no way to make it parallel. If you are considering modifying mysql_upgrade, maybe you can ask help in MySQL internals list, or in maria-discuss list.

Comment: I took a look at the code for mysql_upgrade and it appears to do two things, create an upgrade marker file, run fix_priviliges.sql and then crawl the datadir with mysqlcheck. Should be pretty easy to do this in a bash script and parallelize the check.

Answer (score 1):

Run:
`mysqlcheck --check-upgrade --all-databases > mysql-check.log`

This will produce a file with all required actions.

Now, run:

`$ for t in $(cat mysql-check.log |grep -B1 REPAIR | egrep -v 'REPAIR|--');
    do echo "mysql -e 'REPAIR TABLE $t;'" >> upgrade.sql; done`

`$ for t in $(cat mysql-check.log |grep -B1 ALTER | egrep -v 'ALTER|--');
    do echo "mysql -e 'ALTER TABLE $t FORCE;'" >> upgrade.sql; done`

This will produce file with all the required commands.

Now, the commands execute in parallel:

`parallel -j 4 -- < upgrade.sql`

In the end just to make sure all the required upgrades ran, execute:
`mysql_upgrade --force`

Taken from here: https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/07/14/little-trick-upgrading-mysql-5-7/

See this link for more tricks. like running commands in the order of file sizes, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Suggest you switch to a topology that includes multiple masters.  Then upgrading, schema changes, etc, *may* be able to be done without downtime other than some flavor of failover.

With traditional replication have two servers replicating from each other, but write to only one.  Failover is making the other machine writable and pointing all write-clients to it.  Depending on the details of the upgrade, there may be issues about what gets replicated, when.

(Sorry, I proffer this for discussion, but without all the details.)

Comment: We are, already in a multi master state. The problem is not down time but the sheer duration of upgrading all of the servers that I have.